# Write SQL other optimized way

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below query which I have written like below. Actually, I want to get two diff. colors from colors table. Please look into it and can you tell me It is optimized way? Can I write below query other optimized way?

```
SELECT d.*, 
(SELECT c.clr_title FROM colors AS c WHERE c.id = d.base_color_id) AS base_color, 
(SELECT c.clr_title FROM colors AS c WHERE c.id = d.overlay_color_id) AS overlay_color  
FROM indira.dress AS d
WHERE id=669;
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what's the problem with this one?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to get an equivalent result:

```
SELECT d.*
     , b.clr_title AS base_color
     , o.clr_title AS overlay_color
  FROM indira.dress d
  LEFT
  JOIN colors b ON b.id = d.base_color_id
  LEFT
  JOIN colors o ON b.id = d.overlay_color_id
 WHERE d.id=669
```

The correlated subqueries in the SELECT list can be expensive for large sets. But for returning a single row, that's not going to be a performance issue, since those subqueries will get executed only once.

In a more general case, for returning lots of rows, using a JOIN is usually more efficient.

You likely already have suitable indexes.  For optimum performance, you'd want an index `ON indira.dress(id)` (likely already the primary key) and `ON colors (id)` (again, likely already the primary key).  There's likely no performance benefit of adding a covering index.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option. I don't know what columns you do have on dress table so you will likely have to call the ones you out in select and group but this should work.

Not sure if it would be any faster/slower but wanted to give you more options ;-)

Here it is in sql fiddle where I also show what would happen if null was given for overlay. -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ebc82/3

```
SELECT
    d.name
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN d.base_color_id = c.id THEN c.clr_title ELSE NULL END) base_color
    ,MAX(CASE WHEN d.overlay_color_id = c.id THEN c.clr_title ELSE NULL END) overlay_color
FROM
    dress d
INNER JOIN colors c ON 
    c.Id IN (d.base_color_id, d.overlay_color_id)
WHERE
    d.id = 669
GROUP BY 
    d.name
```

Comment: That looks like it would work, but the query is not intuitive. I'd recommend against this approach just for readability.

Comment: It does work as proven by sqlfiddle. Optimization was mentioned in OP not readability. He should test all options and make his decision that way if performance is his main concern.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're restricting to a single record, it's probably just fine. But you could always join against the color table twice, like:

```
select
    d.*
    ,base_color.clr_title base_color
    ,overlay_color.clr_title overlay_color
from
    indira.dress d
left join
    colors base_color on d.base_color_id = base_color.id
left join
    colors overlay_color on d.overlay_color_id = overlay_color.id
where
    d.id = 669
```

Comment: Can you tell me which one is faster?

Comment: In real-life, with this type of query, they'll both be so ridiculously fast it's not even worth measuring (assuming the `id` columns on both tables are the primary keys). It's a style decision at this point. For a more complex query or set of joins, you'd have to run some analysis on the two options.

Comment: @Jimit - `Can you tell me?` is probably best answered with `can you work it out yourself?`  Try setting up a test system, and measuring the performance in your own real world setup.

Comment: I banchmarked on both query but query written by me is little bit faster...
Jimit: 0.328 sec / 0.000 sec
Joe: 0.343 sec / 0.000 sec